# What's the most secure way to store and use API keys and secret?

Tags: c#, .net, security, encryption

It's for a desktop app. I have an API key and secret but I don't know the most secure way to store and use them.

If my computer was lost or hacked for example, I want the keys and secret to be worthless but I assume this is not very easy to do.

Comment: lost or hacked are two different scenarios. Smartcard, perhaps.

Comment: @zaitsman the OP never said they are the same scenario.

Comment: @CodingYoshi There is no universal way to protect against both. Protecting against hackers using meltdown won't necessarily save you from the computer being stolen; and many of the techniques are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Are the API keys/secret accessing some resource _you control_? If so, then "you" can invalidate any client by resetting it on the resource. If your computer was stolen or hacked you'll still need to "know" if/when such an event occurs...

Comment: @EdSF Yes they are in my control. But I assume there must be better ways than storing my keys in an ascii file.

Comment: Well, you can certainly do due diligence by _not_ storing in a text file - e.g. registry, obfuscation, etc. Though in the end, you'll _still_ need to know about a stolen or hack "event" to react to it one way or the other.

Comment: From a practical point of view, i usually do this for Windows apps: generate a new machine key locked to a given user's sid OR World Sid for service apps, and encrypt the data i have with this machine key. I then stick it into the registry etc. If they try to copy that out from the machine - it is useless; they'd also need to copy the key.

This is not really a protection however, because the attacked who hacked your user owns the creds; smartcards/HSM are the only way to protect against the in-memory access (essentially the keys are meant to never leave the device).

Comment: But the above protects you far enough from a) anyone accidentally opening that registry key/file and wondering 'wow, what's that, let me edit that' and b) cases where the machine is stolen but the attacker does not know the password for the user. However, if your machine is not protected by Bitlocker or a similar encryption solution, they can always reset the base Administrator password, reset ACLs on the machine key, and decrypt that password.

Comment: there are many similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840717/store-and-encrypt-a-password-locally/48841262#48841262

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to store your keys securely in Azure Keyvault https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/

That's exactly what its built for.  Then the keys are never on your machine, so losing it doesn't matter.

Comment: How does this map to a desktop app?

Comment: It can't connect to the internet ?  You didn't mention "offline capability"